# Insert boolean value into sqlite table

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert

I created a table `MYTABLE`

```
CREATE TABLE "MYTABLE" (
       "surname" VARCHAR,
       "name" VARCHAR,
       "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,
       "flag" BOOL);
```

when I insert a record with:

```
INSERT INTO "MYTABLE" VALUES ("Super","Mario","94", true);
```

I get an error message, that `no such column: true`. If I use this:

```
INSERT INTO "MYTABLE" VALUES ("Super","Mario","94", "true");
```

I don't get any error, but when i read that record with `rs.getBoolean("flag")` I get false.

Finally, i tried this

```
INSERT INTO "MYTABLE" VALUES ("Super","Mario","94", 1);
```

the `rs.getBoolean("flag")` returns `true`. So the lesson here is that the boolean values in Sqlite are inserted with 0/1 ?

Comment: Yes, both in SQLite and other databases (eg SQL Server). BOOL is essentially a BIT, not a true Boolean. In Oracle even that name is missing and `NUMBER(1)` is used instead

Comment: Σ' ευχαριστώ @PanagiotisKanavos ! If you want post it as an answer to take the credits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the BOOL type is synonymous to a BIT in many databases, including SQLite and SQL Server. Other databases, like Oracle, do not even have a boolean type and a NUMBER(1) field is used to store boolean values by convention.

Answer (score 5):

SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class.Boolean values are stored as integers 0 and 1.
[source](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: You should make it clear the text of this answer is copied from [SQLite's page on datatypes](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), otherwise it may be considered plagiarism

Comment: "Plagiarism" in respect to 16 words feels like an overstatement. But the source link is helpful.